# How to control the progressbar appear/disappear like loading in android fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar

I want to implement the loading progressbar when I read the file.

For example , some `fileManager APP` will show the progressbar to denote loading when it read the file from SD card.

I know it can use `android:fromDegrees="0" android:toDegrees="360"` to make the progressbar always turn.

But in `Fragment`. How to show the progressbar(loading) when I want it appear. And close the `progressbar` when I want it disappear?

The pseudo code like the following:

```
If( ReadingFile == true ) {

//Show the progressbar

}else if( ReadingFinish == true ){

//Close the progressbar

}
```

Should I write the `progressbar` to a `new Fragment`.
If I want it to show , add the `fragment` ?

or does there has other method to implement ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. 
**The classic style** (old style) 
 
Display a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) on top of your Fragment and/or Activity. 
**Modern style** (new style - google play uses it) 
Make a `Layout` (xml) in which there is a `ProgressBar` in the center of your layout and Your every other components (EditText, TextView, ListView etc..) as they should be. 
It will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        .... ..../>

    <EditText 
        .... />

    <ListView ....></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your Activity or Fragment get the id of the progressbar and RelativeLayout(OR whatever layout you would prefer) and then

```
if(Realfile) {
     mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else {
     mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**EDIT :**
And you can also use [ProgressFragment](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment)

Comment: not sure Modern style you described is good while loading file.
If martin-wun use actionbar in his application more simple and native way - show progress like on [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tbLkn.png)

Comment: @x90 not Good while loading? Why not?

Comment: @x90 I close the actionbar

Comment: I get a `multiple root tags` error for the xml file. How do you solve this?